# Spark: Flatten simple multi-column DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, flatten, flatmap

**How to flatten a simple (i.e. no nested structures) dataframe into a list?**
My problem set is detecting all the node pairs that have been changed/added/removed from a table of node pairs.

This means I have a "before" and "after" table to compare. Combining the before and after dataframe yields rows that describe where a pair appears in one dataframe but not the other.

```
Example:
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|before.id1 |before.id2 |after.id1  |after.id2  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       null|       null|         E2|         E3|
|         B3|         B1|       null|       null|
|         I1|         I2|       null|       null|
|         A2|         A3|       null|       null|
|       null|       null|         G3|         G4|
```

The goal is to get a list of all the (distinct) nodes in the entire dataframe which would look like:

```
{A2,A3,B1,B3,E2,E3,G3,G4,I1,I2}
```

Potential approaches:

- Union all the columns separately and distinct
- flatMap and distinct
- map and flatten

Since the structure is well known and simple it seems like there should be an equally straightforward solution. **Which approach, or others, would be the simplest approach?**

Other notes

- Order of id1-id2 pair is only important to for change detection
- Order in the resulting list is not important
- DataFrame is between 10k and 100k rows
- distinct in the resulting list is nice to have, but not required; assuming is trivial with the distinct operation

Comment: So why is there no timestamp then? Order of tuples is thus significant? Many files to process in 1 run?

Comment: @thebluephantom timestamp is not needed since there is essentially a "before" and "after" table. Order of tuples is significant but somewhat out of scope since I have a dataframe of 4 columns with comparable values. No files to run, only this dataframe but it is considerable in size.

Comment: Where I come from some form of timestamping is always req'd - many projects with that approach you just mentioned mean -> non-deterministic outcomes. Good luck though

Comment: Timestamping in similar situations may reduce the need for even solving this scenario in the first place - but all the same I'd like to know how to flatten a simple dataframe like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following, converting all rows into seqs and then collect all rows and then flatten the data and remove null value:

```
val df = Seq(("A","B"),(null,"A")).toDF 
val result = df.rdd.map(_.toSeq.toList)
   .collect().toList.flatten.toSet - null
```